# How can I get my cream pie to set?

Tags: pie

I have made a coconut cream pie and after being in the fridge overnight, it did not set up. Is there anything I can do now to get it to firm up? The coconut flakes are already in it, so I don't think I can remove the filling to bring it to a boil again.

I used 1 1/2 cups of coconut milk and 1 1/2 cups half and half, with 1/3 cup corn starch, 2 eggs and sugar. I cooked it in the microwave, stirring every 40 seconds or so for about 6 minutes total, until there were bubbles on the top of the filling.

Any ideas on how to firm up this pie, so it can actually be cut into pieces?

Comment: I waited most of today to see if someone else answered, but I think sadly you will have to write this pie off, and try again next time.  I would not do a cream pie in the microwave.  Suggest the oven, and cooking to a temperature of 180 degrees F, or until the center is barely set but giggles when you shake the pie pan a bit.

Answer (score 3):

There are thickening agents you can use without reheating. They won't give you the texture you expect from a starch-thickened pie, but you will be able to cut it. Gelatine is probably your best bet. Others, like xanthan, will make it gooey, but it will still flow a little after being cut.

By the way, having flakes in it is not a problem for cooking it again. If you mean that you put them on top, you can just stir them in for the reheating. Won't look that good, but will be firm.

When making cream pie filling, always do it on the stove *and* make sure that you really brought it to a boil. Egg yolks contain an enzyme which liquidifies starch. The enzyme is deactivated at above 90°C. If you don't heat a mixture with eggs and starch (and flour) enough, it will turn into a soup after a day.

Answer (score 1):

my pie would not thicken either. I poured it back into the pan and took butter and more flour that I mashed to form a paste and then stirred it into the warmed filling stirring until It thickened up and I then returned it to the graham cracker crust. The coconut did just fine. I hope this helps anyone else with this problem.